# Specific Wifi network connection history in OSX

Tags: macos, wifi

Is there a way to see the history of connections to a specific wifi network in the last couple of months.

The idea is to focus on one particular SSID and on which days my laptop connected to that network over a period of time.

Is this logged or available for review after the fact?

Comment: History as in which SSIDs were used at any point in time, or just a list of SSIDs that have ever been used on the Mac?

Comment: @JesseP. Yeah. Actually interested in one particular SSID and on which days my laptop connected to that network over a period of time.

Comment: What exactly are you looking to accomplish with this info?  Connecting to an SSID is *not* the same as connecting to a network; you can authenticate to an AP without actually being allowed on a network.

Answer (score 6):

> Specific WiFi network connection history in OSX

Try using the following command in Terminal

```
log show --predicate '(processImagePath contains "configd") && (eventMessage contains "en0: SSID {enter your SSID name} ")' --style syslog --last 1d
```

Change `last 1d` (1 day to any days you want to look)

It will list all Dates and Time when your Mac was connected to specified SSID (network name)

This is a sample from my Mac looking at 3 days

[image]

More about WiFi networks on your Mac..

If you have the option "Remember Networks" enabled, all Networks that you joined at one time will be there, even Years back.

[image: all WiFi]

You can also find the last log in information for each Network in your Keychain.

[image: key chain]

However, that does not tells you specific activity per Network, only the last log in time.

Depending what are you looking for you can find the detailed WiFi logs in `/private/var/log/`

Also you can use following command to show you the history (Years) for all Networks your Mac connected.

```
defaults read /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences |grep LastConnected -A 7
```

EXAMPLE

[image: History]

Comment: This is a nice way to see one data point and illustrates why the history isn’t preserved over time for multiple connections to one SSID. +1 for super detail and getting closer to a solution

Answer (score 2):

No, Apple doesn’t log or present this in a quick and easy way to retrieve - especially over months of time.

However all is not lost, there is an amazing app that logs WiFi quite well.

- https://www.adriangranados.com/apps/wifisignal

I’m sure someone could script up a solution as well, but I’ve been very satisfied with this author’s various WiFi tools and blogs and it logs the data you need in a super clean and useful manner.

Comment: I think I found it  `log show --predicate '(processImagePath contains "configd") && (eventMessage contains "en0: SSID {enteryours} ")' --style syslog --last 1d` change the 1d to more days

Comment: @Buscar웃 That's very promising - a unified log search that's super useful. I'm seeing on Mojave that you get lots of entries but I could see making a tool to dump or process those log entries into changes in SSID or know that when the message was logged there was a connection. I'll report back, initially I'm seeing on average a log message an hour for a Mac that's lightly used and has a wired ethernet connection as well.