# Is it possible to find precisely the history of WiFis connected on my MacBook Pro 2017 with the times?

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, history

Is it possible for me to find out when and what WiFi routers my MacBook has been connected to over the last few months/1 year?

Comment: Have you tried a google search? "mac wifi history" might be a good start. The first result for me was especially clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specific Wifi network connection history in OSX](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345654/specific-wifi-network-connection-history-in-osx)